# "Uncaught TypeError: f.isVisible is not a function" with createjs and pixi

Tags: javascript, adobe, createjs, pixi.js

I have a pixijs based website which also has an Adobe Animate CC generated createjs animation. I want to call the createjs animation's initAnimation() function when the pixijs loader is done, but if I call that function from the function which is called by the PIXI.loader.load(), I get Uncaught TypeError: f.isVisible is not a function error. When I call it from the body's onload event handler function, it works fine, but the animation starts before the pixi loader loaded all the resources.

Here is my code:

```
function init () {  
stage = new PIXI.Container();

renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(w, h);

PIXI.loader
    .add("images/1.png")
    .on("progress", loadHandler)
    .load(function () {
        initAnimation();
        ...
    });
}

function initAnimation () {
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
handleComplete();
}
...
```

Comment: There is a important code missing from the example I would say. I would suggest to make an example to https://jsfiddle.net/ or https://plnkr.co/

Answer (score 1):

The `object.isVisible is not a function` error happens in CreateJS when you add something to the display list that is not a DisplayObject.

Each tick, the Stage checks if each object should be rendered, which runs the `isVisible` check.

Ensure you are adding only DisplayObjects (Shape, Sprite, Bitmap, MovieClip, Text) to the stage.